# JWT User Invalidating the token on logout

Tags: spring-security, jwt

I am using **jwt** token with spring **security**.

After successfully **generating** the **token** on login and passing it to my Reactjs application in localStorage object. I have one problem that on **logout** I **delete** the token but still using the same token I can hit secured api through Postman.

Since I know that token is **not expired** but is there any way that I can **re-issue** new token if the user keeps on interacting and I keep the expiry very small like 5 minutes.

Comment: Since anybody who knows request url and params can hit the running services therefore is there any way to protect them

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

1: Re-issue new token after every api response and update the token in the localstorage object of react app using a filter

2: Save all issued token in a repository/cache or in memory then delete token from this repository on logout. While validating the JWT token add one more check to see if the token exists in the repository.

Comment: how do I delete repository cache delete works only on client side. What if I issue a token and using that same token I hit secured api after logout from postman it works. It shouldn't allow to access secured api after logout(do something at backend)

Comment: Delete from repostiory cache before deleting the token on client side. Simple. Create an API to delete this token from backend on successfull deletion remove the token from client side / localstorage.  Implement your own LogoutHandler

Comment: Once I do this `return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(Long.toString(userPrincipal.getId()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();`

I can't change the token which my security has. If you have read properly we can't update token or delete it.

Comment: if you have any reference please provide

Comment: `public class CustomLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {
    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
 String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
 String token = authHeader.replace("Bearer ", "");
 try {
     JWT jwt = JWTParser.parse(token);
     String subject = jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getSubject();
     tokenRepo.deleteTokenBySubject(subject);
 } catch (ParseException e) {
 }
    }
}`   regsiter similar logout handler in your security config

Comment: Before returning newly created tokens make sure you save them in the tokenRepo. And while validating token check if that token exists in the tokenRepo

Comment: Okay here is the solution I looked in internet that I can use blacklist repository where on logout I keep all the expired token with expiry datetime and on incoming request I check if the requested token is blacklist repo or not if it is there then I would say failed else proceed. The thing I want to ask is whether I keep the check in security where I going use this repo? I am going to use very similar to Redis i.e Apache Ignite. And I would use job scheduler to check if time has passed the expiry if it has passed I will delete the token so that I don't crowd my memory with not useful data

Comment: can you tell how to get the expiry date of my token which I created and set while creation of a token